# Gerber interpretation of "clear" on silkscreen

Tags: pcb-fabrication, gerber

I've had some PCBs back from my manufacturer which I haven't used before, and was surprised with some silkscreen printing which I consider to be an error.  The bottom should have had no silkscreen printing at all, but I supplied a Gerber for it to unambiguous.  The boards are well made and the top silkscreen is completely unremarkable and correct.

**My question is: with a just single `%LPC` command and some subsequent `D03` flashes, am I correct there should be no printing?**

The Gerber was made by LibrePCB, which appears to output the desired silkscreen drawing commands followed by clear flashes where there is no soldermask, to prevent silkscreen printing over pads.  If nothing is desired, all you end up with is `%LPC` and the "print-nothing-here" flashes.

`gerbv`, Ucamco's [reference viewer](https://www.ucamco.com/en/gerber/reference-gerber-viewer), Mayhew Labs' [3d viewer](http://mayhewlabs.com/3dpcb) all show a blank image for my file.

Here is that unexciting but correct image (shown with outlines layer):
[image]

I believe that something in the manufacturer's preprocessing, perhaps to do with panelisation, has a bug for a Gerber file with only clear flashes.  Their image is as if I'd asked for a solid white rectangle the exact size of the bounding box of my clear flashes, followed by all the clear flashes.

This following is the essence of my Gerber file, with my interpretations from the Gerber standard revision of 2019-06 at [Ucamco](https://www.ucamco.com/en/gerber/downloads).

```
001:%FSLAX66Y66*%                 | Format specification 6.6, 6.6
002:%MOMM*%                       | File is in millimetres
003:G01*                          | Set Linear Interpolation graphics mode
004:G74*                          | Set single-quadrant mode
005:%ADD10C,1.7*%                 | Aperture definition D10 = circle 1.7
... few more aperture definitions
013:%LPC*%                        | Load polarity is 'clear'
014:D10*                          | Set current aperture = D10 (circle 1.7)
015:X15240000Y5080000D03*         | Flash (15.240000, 5.080000) with D10 (circle 1.7)
016:X15240000Y10160000D03*        | Flash (15.240000, 10.160000) with D10 (circle 1.7)
017:D11*                          | Set current aperture = D11 (circle 1.6)
018:X20320000Y-5080000D03*        | Flash (20.320000, -5.080000) with D11 (circle 1.6)
more D1X and X..Y..D03 flashes
078:M02*                          | End of file
```

Comment: What did they actually print? What did your fab notes say about silkscreen? For example did you include "Silkscreen on top side only"?

Comment: My question is really about interpreting Gerber rather than understanding this manufacturer.  What they printed is in the question: "Their image is as if I'd asked for a solid white rectangle the exact size of the bounding box of my clear flashes, followed by all the clear flashes."